# Is possible to add a namespace to the inputs in a form divided by partials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I'm using simple form and I have a long form divided in partials, each partial represents a category.

[image]

For example, identification_form is:

[image]

I'd like the inputs to get a name like this:

[image]

Is possible to do this?

I can change the names by myself, but the problem is simple_form is not able to create the names for the stat_date and end_date (act[start_date(1i), act[start_date(2i), act[start_date(3i), it adds the same name for the three inputs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is!

```
f.fields_for :identification do |identification_form|
  identification_form.input :name
```

The above will give you:

```
<input type="text" name="act[identification][name]" />
```

This should then work with dates.

Edit:

I think you should be using `date_select` rather than `input`.

Comment: That's exactly what I need! Thank you very much!